# Requirements for root CA certificate to add in iOS

Tags: ios, openssl, ca

I issued my own CA certificate to enable https for my development environment.
On my Windows PC i was able to add my root CA. On iOS i can install it and it shows that it is verified but when i go to General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings the certificate does not show up.

Some information about the root CA.

Input:
`openssl x509 -in ca.pem -text -noout`

Output:

````
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            [...]
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = Some-Country, ST = Some-State, O = Some-Company
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul  7 18:45:56 2022 GMT
            Not After : Jul  4 18:45:56 2032 GMT
        Subject: C = Some-Country, ST = Some-State, O = Some-Company
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    [...]
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                [...]
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:[...]

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         [...] ```
````

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that the root CA I created was valid for 10 years. Since 1st September 2020 Apple limits the validity period to a maximum of 397 days.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211025